# How to create an ArrayList with objects of another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, shapes

So I have an ArrayList "NamedShape"

```
ArrayList<NamedShape> shapes = new ArrayList<NamedShape>();
```

that contains a Shape and a String and what i want is to have another ArrayList "Connection" that will hold two fields but both are "NamedShape". My ArrayList "Connection" will then look like this:

[image]

Here is my class for "NamedShape":

```
public class NamedShape {
    private String name;
    private Shape shape;
    public NamedShape( String name, Shape shape ){
        this.name = name;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name; 
    }
    public Shape getShape(){ 
        return shape; 
    }
}
```

**Here is my Connection class:**

```html
 public class Connection     {
    private NamedShape namedShape1;
    private NamedShape namedShape2;
    public Connection(??){
        ??
    }
   }
```

Can you please help me to create this new ArrayList "Connection"?

Comment: what's the structure of Connection class?

Comment: So, you know what is constructor and how to create getters, what's the problem?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg     That's my problem, i do know how to write constructors but for the "Connection" class, am stuck. Please see my above edited code.

Comment: @LanaM can't you just write the same this as for `NamedShape`?

Comment: Thank you Mr, i was able to do it. See my answer. But how do i add data to this ArrayList "Connection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, I was able to do it. :D

```html
ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<Connection>();
       
        
     
     
        
   public class Connection     {
    private NamedShape namedShape1;
    private NamedShape namedShape2;
    public Connection(NamedShape namedShape1,NamedShape namedShape2){
        this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
        this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
    }
    
    public NamedShape getNamedShape1(){
        return namedShape1;
    }
    public NamedShape getNamedShape2(){
        return namedShape2;
    }
    
    public void setNameShape1(){
        this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
    }
    
    public void setNameShape2(){
        this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You found it yourself. Great

Comment: @user4559929 but then how can i add data to this ArrayList "Connection?

Answer (score 2):

You may create another class that contains two NamedShape Objects.

```
public class Connection {
    private NamedShape namedShapeOne;
    private NamedShape namedShapeTwo;
    .............
    .............
    .............
}
```

Now create array list as you wish

```
List<Connection> connectionList = new ArrayList<Connection>();
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you please see my above edited code and help me out with the constructor and the getters/setters?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class `Connection` -

```
public class Connection {

 private NamedShape namedShape;

  //constructors
 //getter setters

}
```

Then you can create new array list of `Connection` -

```
List<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
```

Comment: Please see my above code for "Connection" class. I'm having problem with the constructor and the getter/setters method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is self-explaining. If you create an `ArrayList<Connection>` that means you already have a `Connection` class in which you have references for two NamedShape objects. So, as previous answers suggested, you just need to declare a `Connection` class.

If you want to go without the Connection class, your new ArrayList will look like this:

`ArrayList<ArrayList<NamedShape>>`

That is, an `ArrayList` containing `ArrayList`s containing `NamedShape`s.